# FXMLLoader raises "Location is not set", even though file exists on location

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX project that I compile/run with Maven. This is how I load my login screen:

```java
String path = "/org/openjfx/fxml/login.fxml";
URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
```

It runs neatly. `url` is evaluated to `file:/home/allan/IdeaProjects/california-maven/target/classes/org/openjfx/fxml/login.fxml`.

However, when I try to render another FXML file with this same code, I get `javafx.fxml.LoadException caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.`. The file's full url (passed to `FXMLLoader`) is `file:/home/allan/IdeaProjects/california-maven/target/classes/org/openjfx/fxml/sign-up.fxml`.

Which is odd, since both files exist on that location:

[image: a print of the folder structure, depicting that both files exist on that location]

I wonder if this is a problem with `sign-up.fxml`. Code below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import org.openjfx.components.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minViewportHeight="768.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefViewportWidth="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" styleClass=".root-scroll-pane" stylesheets="@../css/index.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.openjfx.controllers.SignUpController">
   <content>
      <VBox prefHeight="1068.0" prefWidth="1024.0" styleClass="root-vbox" stylesheets="@../css/sign-up.css">
         <children>
            <HBox spacing="25.0">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="55.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <children>
                  <GoBackButton />
                  <Label text="Criar conta">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="-20.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <FormField fx:id="nameField" fieldLabelText="Nome:" promptText="Ex: Allan">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="40.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </FormField>
            <FormField fx:id="usernameField" fieldLabelText="Nome de usuário:" promptText="Ex: allan">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="40.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </FormField>
            <FormField fx:id="emailField" fieldLabelText="Email:" promptText="Ex: allan@agill.com">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="40.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </FormField>
            <FormField fx:id="passwordField" fieldLabelText="Senha:" isPasswordField="true">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="40.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </FormField>
            <FormField fx:id="confirmPasswordField" fieldLabelText="Confirme sua senha:" isPasswordField="true">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="40.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </FormField>
            <Button fx:id="signUpButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#signUpButtonClicked" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="sign-up-button" stylesheets="@../css/sign-up.css" text="CRIAR">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="85.0" top="60.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

**EDIT 1:**

The login screen is loaded in `Main.java`. The sign up screen is loaded by a file called `NavigationService.java`, that lives inside `org.openjfx.services`. This is the loading code on NavigationService:

```java
 private Scene buildScene(String routeName) {
        String path = "/org/openjfx/fxml/" + routeName + ".fxml";
        URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
        System.out.println("Trying to load: " + url);

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);

            Dimensions dimensions = Dimensions.getPrefferedSize(routeName);

            return new Scene(root, dimensions.getWidth(), dimensions.getHeight());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Full stack trace:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/allan/IdeaProjects/california-maven/target/classes/org/openjfx/fxml/sign-up.fxml:18

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at org.openjfx/org.openjfx.services.NavigationService.buildScene(NavigationService.java:43)
    at org.openjfx/org.openjfx.services.NavigationService.push(NavigationService.java:55)
    at org.openjfx/org.openjfx.controllers.LoginController.signUpLinkClicked(LoginController.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink.fire(Hyperlink.java:156)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at org.openjfx/org.openjfx.components.GoBackButton.<init>(GoBackButton.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    ... 67 more
```

**EDIT 2:**

**GoBackButton.java**

```java
package org.openjfx.components;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.openjfx.services.NavigationService;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class GoBackButton extends Button {
    public GoBackButton() {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/org/openjfx/fxml/go-back-button.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);

        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void onAction() {
        NavigationService.getInstance().pop();
    }
}
```

**go-back-button.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>

<fx:root mnemonicParsing="false" fx:controller="org.openjfx.components.GoBackButton" onAction="#onAction" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="98.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;" styleClass="go-back-button" type="Button" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView fitHeight="64.0" fitWidth="48.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <Image url="@../img/arrow-left.png" />
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</fx:root>
```

The error still happens when I try to render the sign up page, but now the [StackTrace](https://hastebin.com/ibalesimah.sql) changed. Link to pastebin since SO won't let me make a post this long.

Comment: It really says "IllegalStateException"? Post the actual code you are using to load `sign-up.fxml`, and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Yes, it does! I didn't put the whole StackTrace in the post, since it's lengthy, but the last "block" is indeed `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.`.

Comment: Post the code that loads the fxml and complete stack trace (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Done it. Thanks in advance, your help is being of much value!

Comment: Oh boy... I forgot to update resource loading code on GoBackButton. I updated it, but now what I'm getting is an StackOverflow error T_T
I'll edit the post with more code, sorry for making you wait!!

Comment: Edited it! Thanks a lot, James.

Comment: Hm... And how do I reference the controller's `onAction` method? I removed `fx:controller` and the screen renders fine, but now the button doesn't do anything. I tried setting the `onAction` behaviour inside `initialize()`, but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error originates from creating the custom component `GoBackButton`, as can be seen from the stack trace, which refers to line 18 of `sign-up.fxml` (which is just `<GoBackButton/>`) and subsequently line 18 of `GoBackButton.java`, which is the `loader.load()` line.

With the corrected URL for `go-back-button.fxml`, you get a stack overflow exception as the [custom component pattern](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) is incorrectly implemented.

In your code, `<GoBackButton/>` in `sign-up.fxml` initiates a call to the `GoBackButton` constructor. This constructor loads `go-back-button.fxml`, which has the `fx:controller` attribute set to `GoBackButton`, which causes a call to the `GoBackButton` constructor. This continues recursively, with repeated calls to `loader.load()` and the constructor.

Instead, you need to set the controller to the *current instance* of `GoBackButton` which is being constructed. You do this by omitting the `fx:controller` attribute in `go-back-button.fxml` and calling `loader.setController(this)` before calling `loader.load()`.

Additionally, since the custom component uses a *dynamic root* (with `<fx:root>`), you need to explicitly set the root of the `FXMLLoader`.

The resulting code should be

`go-back-button.fxml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>

<fx:root mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAction" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="98.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;" styleClass="go-back-button" type="Button" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView fitHeight="64.0" fitWidth="48.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <Image url="@../img/arrow-left.png" />
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</fx:root>
```

and

`GoBackButton.java`

```
package org.openjfx.components;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.openjfx.services.NavigationService;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class GoBackButton extends Button {
    public GoBackButton() {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/org/openjfx/fxml/go-back-button.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);

        try {
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void onAction() {
        NavigationService.getInstance().pop();
    }
}
```

Note: I've never actually tried setting an `onAction` handler directly on a `fx:root` element, but I believe it should work. You can also just do

```
    public GoBackButton() {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/org/openjfx/fxml/go-back-button.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);

        try {
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.load();
            setOnAction(e -> onAction());
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works smoothly. I thought I would never do this, I was almost giving up on adding dependency management to my project. Thanks a lot!!